# Why does creating this memoryview raise a ValueError only when assigning to a variable?

Tags: python, numpy, read-eval-print-loop, memoryview, structured-array

Pythons [memoryview](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) does [not support `datetime64` or `timedelta`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4983).  Ok.  But when I try to create a `memoryview` of a structured array that includes a `datetime64` or `timedelta`, it appears to work... *unless I assign it to a variable*!

```
In [19]: memoryview(zeros(10, dtype=[("A", "m8[s]")]))
Out[19]: <memory at 0x7f1d455d6048>

In [20]: x = memoryview(zeros(10, dtype=[("A", "m8[s]")]))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
ValueError: cannot include dtype 'm' in a buffer

In [21]: x = _19

In [22]: x
Out[22]: <memory at 0x7f1d455d6048>
```

This seriously challenges my understanding of the way Python fundamentally works.  How can `f()` and `x = f()` be different, considering that (1) IPythons REPL assigns the output to `_19` anyway, and (2) the function/class `memoryview` has no way of knowing what the caller is going to do with its output?

I am running the code on Python 3.4.1, numpy 1.10.0.dev+fbcc24f, on Linux 2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64, Scientific Linux release 6.6.

---

**EDIT**

On Python 3.5, numpy 1.10.4, I get:

```
In [50]: memoryview(numpy.zeros(10, dtype=[("A", "m8[s]")]))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
ValueError: cannot include dtype 'm' in a buffer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-5d5ac6c085fa> in <module>()
----> 1 memoryview(numpy.zeros(10, dtype=[("A", "m8[s]")]))

SystemError: <class 'memoryview'> returned a result with an error set
```

I have filed a [bug with numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7270), although I'm not quite sure that's where the problem lies.

Comment: Despite the ValueError, the assignment in `[20]` succeeded.  Take a look at the variable `x` immediately after the assignment.  You'll see that it has, in fact, been assigned a value.  (Sorry, I don't know what is causing the ValueError.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Huh, indeed it does.  It didn't occur to me to check.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the `theading` module of python (try running the above code in a script without ipython), I've never seen anything like it before.

Comment: If I run the same sequence in a plain python shell, I don't get the ValueError in the assigment statement.  The ValueError occurs when I try to show `x` by just typing the name and hitting return.  So `>>> x = memoryview(...)` "works", but then `>>> x` raises the ValueError.

Comment: Where is the threading library involved?  With the actual problem deep in my code (using `joblib`), the result is a traceback pointing at an entirely unrelated location, unless I step through using `ipdb`, which results in no related error at all.

Comment: There's something very strange going on here.  The `ValueError` actually occurs when you execute *any* statement after the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something very odd going on here.

```
>>> memoryview(zeros(10, dtype=[("A", "m8[s]")]))
<memory at 0x102654348>
>>> 
ValueError: cannot include dtype 'm' in a buffer
```

My conjecture is that this is related to https://bugs.python.org/issue23571.  Some C function underlying `memoryview` is both returning a non-null result and setting an error flag.  This apparently causes the error to be raised when the *next* statement is executed!  In Python 3.5, the interpreter raises a `SystemError` instead when this condition occurs.

It seems like the real bug here is with the `memoryview` function, not with numpy.